# Dockerfile Add command failing to locate target folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, devops

I have a Dockerfile in the root directory of a Spring Boot application and also I have a target folder in the same path as shown in below structure:

```
|--src
  |--main
     |--com.abc.myApp
|--target/xyz.jar
|--Dockerfile
|--pom.xml
```

My Dockerfile looks as below:

```
From openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /opt
ADD /target/xyz.jar .
```

When I try to execute using following command:

```
docker build . -t xyz
```

I am getting error as below:

```
Step 3/3 : ADD /target/xyz.jar .
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder225663872/target/xyz.jar: no such file or directory
```

The Dockerfile is present at /opt/MyApp/Dockerfile and target folder is present at /opt/MyApp/target/xyz.jar

Where am I going wrong? Also I do not have any `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: Try with removing the initial slash of the directory. ADD target/xyz.jar .

Comment: have tried that but still facing same issue..i am still wondering why Dockerfile refering /var/lib path instead of /opt or the Dockerfile location

Comment: try running `./mvnw clean package` to build project first

Comment: Since there is slash, path will be from root. Also the WORKDIR you provided is the directory on the container and not on you local system.

Answer (score 2):

As the the jar file will also contain the version number you better use this solution

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

ARG is there because COPY doesn't work with wildcards.

And as already commented you have to call first:

```
mvn package
```

Please read more about Spring Boot and Docker: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Starting with Spring 2.3 you even don't need a Dockerfile. You can run

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

Also read this: https://www.baeldung.com/dockerizing-spring-boot-application

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention where you are building your images. For example, If you are in your home directory :-

/home/user/

and your have your Dockerfile and jar placed in the same directory. Your Docker file should have the following entry :-

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ADD item-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar itemapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","itemapp.jar"]
```

Add should not have the /target path.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/jenkins-project.jar jenkins-project.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/jenkins-project.jar"]
```

This name of jar file "jenkins-project.jar" should be set in the pom.xml file as well in finalName.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>jenkins-project</finalName> 
</build>
```

This finalName should be set name as the jar file name.